# LibCurl SFTP get full list of files

Tags: list, directory, sftp, libcurl

I need to get full file list from 2 servers (ftp and sftp) with libcurl.

Libcurl Information:

```
System: Windows 7;
Wrapper: SourcePawn;
Version: libcurl/7.23.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5 libssh2/1.3.0;
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp.
```

The point is, my code returns full filelist for the ftp server, but not for sftp. for the sftp server I only get one (first line).

here is my code:

```
public RequestFileList()
{   
    new Handle:curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl != INVALID_HANDLE)
    {
        LogMessage("RequestFileList");

        CURL_DEFAULT_OPT(curl);


        curl_easy_setopt_function(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, GetFileList);
        curl_easy_setopt_string(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://xxxxx:5000/");
        curl_easy_setopt_string(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:xxx");
        curl_easy_setopt_int(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_TRY);
        curl_easy_setopt_int(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_easy_perform_thread(curl, onCompleteFilelist, 1);
    }
}
public GetFileList(Handle:hndl, const String:buffer[], const bytes, const nmemb)
{

    LogMessage("%s %i %i", buffer, bytes, nmemb);
}
```

output:

```
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root            0 Mar 27  2014 sys
 1 60
```

if i execute it with cmd:

```
curl -k -u xxx:xxx sftp://xxxx:5000/
```

I get full filelist:

```
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root            0 Mar 27  2014 sys
drwx------    2 root     root        16384 Jul 30  2009 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   22 root     root         4096 Dec 31  2013 work
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         4096 Jul 30  2009 plugin
```

What shall I change to get full filelist?

Here is full log:

```
* About to connect() to xxxxxxxxxxx port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... 
* connected
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
* Using ssh public key file id_dsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file id_dsa
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
L 02/07/2016 - 13:57:36: [pl.smx] STR - drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root            0 Mar 27  2014 sys
 1 60
* Connection #0 to host xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: your write callback probably returns the wrong value so libcurl stops there

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But is there a way to tell curl to return the whole list in one response? It fires callback function for every file/folder

Comment: That's a completely different question, but no libcurl doesn't hold contents, it delivers it to the application as soon as it gets it. See the docs for the write callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [write callback](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) returns the wrong value so libcurl stops there.